# Passing remote parameters in RMI

Tags: parameter-passing, rmi, distributed-computing, stub

I would like to have confirm about RMI theory.

Let us suppose that Client A requests a remote reference of an object O to a Server B.

Well, now if In O interface (Interf) there is a method like:
void foo(Interf obj);

When Client A calls O.foo(O) it passes stub reference (before received ) and then Server does not use its local reference but the Stub Object (received by Client), and so each call on O methods by Server will make use of its TCP/IP service.

Is it Ok?

You should feel free to add some details if you think that those can improve my RMI understanding.

Regards

Comment: It is you that needs to add the details. (1) What do you mean by 'requests a remote reference'? (2) What do you mean by 'does not use its local reference but the Stub object'? (3) What do you mean by 'make use of its TCP/IP service'. (4) Whose 'TCP/IP service'? In other words what is this question actually about?

Comment: Requests a remote reference means:
Interf O = (Interf) Lookup(...);
My question is about the situation in which a Server receives as parameter of a remote methode a remote reference created by itself, and on the fact that Server to use this remote reference doesn't use local reference but the Stub just received. I would like to have a confirm

Comment: Exported remote objects are sent as remote stubs, but the reverse doesn't occur. Why would your client send the server something it already had?

Comment: It's just an example to understand the behind behaviour, however you have not answered at my question!

Comment: As a matter of fact I *have* answered your question: 'the reverse does not occur', but you should note that these are comments, not answers, where I am mostly trying to draw you out to understand what your question actually is, so it can be answered. Any expectation that comments should contain answers is misplaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORBA servers (as used to implement RMI/IIOP, not RMI/JRMP) typically implement a "colocated stub" optimization.  That is, if a server invokes a method on a stub for an object that resides in that same process, the CORBA server will typically avoid TCP/IP and thread pool dispatch overhead.  Instead, the parameters are copied, the method will be invoked on the target object, and the result object is copied and returned.

For reference, Java servers typically implement this optimization.  The generated stub classes use the [Util.isLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/rmi/CORBA/Util.html#isLocal%28javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub%29) method to determine if a stub target is local.  Next, Stub.[_servant_preinvoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/portable/ObjectImpl.html#_servant_preinvoke%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) is called to obtain a reference/proxy to the local servant, and [Util.copyObjects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/rmi/CORBA/Util.html#copyObjects%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.omg.CORBA.ORB%29) (or Util.copyObject) is used to copy parameters and return objects.  (There are additional complexities with exception handling, RemarshalException, etc., but I've outlined the basic flow.)

Comment: This is true of RMI/IIOP. It is definitely *not* true of RMI/JRMP. It would violate the specified semantics of RMI/JRMP to make that optimization.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit that my answer was RMI/IIOP only. I don't have much experience with RMI/JRMP. For my own knowledge, can you give a pointer (or longer explanation) of which semantics are violated? Thanks!

Comment: The [Remote Method Invocation Specification #2.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-objmodel7.html) provides that all arguments and return values are passed by serialization, i.e. by value copy, unless they are exported remote objects, when a stub is passed. Turning RMI into local method invocation would violate that, as local method arguments & results are passed by reference.

Comment: That's exactly what Util.copyObject does: it performs an in-memory serialize/deserialize of the arguments and return values. Why couldn't RMI/JRMP implement the same optimization?

Comment: I guess it could, but it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose there would need to be a predefined utility class for performing the copy or else stubs generated for one system wouldn't be portable to another.  Anyway, thanks for your thoughts.