# RMI Remote Collection without serialization of locale objects

Tags: java, parameter-passing, rmi

Related To: [Passing remote parameters in RMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531561/passing-remote-parameters-in-rmi)

Hello,

I look for a solution for the following problem: I have locale Objects (lets say of type MyObject) that are represented remotely by RemoteObject with a Reference to these Objects.

```
public class RemoteMyObject extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemoteInterface {

  MyObject refToLocale;

  protected RemoteMyObject(MyObject locale) throws RemoteException {
    super();
    refToLocale = locale;
  }

  @Override // MyRemoteInterface
  public void doSomething() throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("did it!");
  }

  public MyObject getLocale() {
    return refToLocale;
  }
}
```

That works as expected. I do not want to serialize `MyObject`, because it has references to other unseriliazable classes and the class-files are enyrypted. Now I have Collections of `MyObject` and I want to manipulate them remotely. So I implemented a `RemoteCollection`.

```
public class MyRemoteCollection extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
RemoteCollection<MyRemoteInterface> {

  Collection<MyObject> localeCollection;

  public MyRemoteCollection(Collection<MyObject> locale) throws RemoteException {
    super();
    localeCollection = locale;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<RemoteMyObject> getItems() throws RemoteException {
    ArrayList<RemoteMyObject> result = new ArrayList<RemoteMyObject>();
    for (MyObject locale : localeCollection) {
      result.add(new RemoteMyObject(locale));
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(MyRemoteInterface obj) {
    MyObject locale = ((RemoteMyObject)obj).getLocale();
    localeCollection.remove(locale);
  }

}
```

The problem is now, that the client calls `getItems()` via RMI and recieves a Collection of Remote/Proxy-Objects. These objects can be used as normal (I can call `doSomething()`) but as soon as I want one of these objects deleted I have a problem: The `delete()`-Method expects an Object that it can cast to `RemoteMyObject` to get the locale reference, but the delivered argument is just a stub and so the cast fails.

**Since the Object was originally created on the server, my question is now if I can get the locale object back or if there is a more elegant solution to solve the Problem?**

Thank you for reading.

For completeness the interfaces and the server and client:

```
public interface MyRemoteInterface extends Remote {

  void doSomething() throws RemoteException;

}

public interface RemoteCollection<REM> extends Remote {

  Collection< ? extends REM> getItems() throws RemoteException;

  void delete(REM obj) throws RemoteException;

}

public class MainServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Registry registry = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
      Collection<MyObject> coll = new ArrayList<>();
      coll.add(new MyObject());
      coll.add(new MyObject());
      coll.add(new MyObject());
      MyRemoteCollection remCol = new MyRemoteCollection(coll);
      registry.rebind("mylist", remCol);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

public class MainClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);
      RemoteCollection<MyRemoteInterface> remCol = (RemoteCollection<MyRemoteInterface>)registry.lookup("mylist");
      for (MyRemoteInterface item : remCol.getItems()) {
        item.doSomething();
        remCol.delete(item);
      }
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException  e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EJP said in the comments, you need a map for mapping the stubs to the real/local objects. I added a new Interface

```
interface IdentifieableRemoteObject {

  ObjID getObjectID();

}
```

Then I created a Map from `ObjID` to the concrete instance of the implementing class.

```
class RemoteObjectCache {

  private static WeakHashMap<ObjID, WeakReference<IdentifieableRemoteObject>> cache = new WeakHashMap<>;

  public static void register(IdentiefieableRemoteObject iro) {
    cache.put(iro.getID(), iro);
  }

  public IdentifieableRemoteObject lookUp(ObjID id) {
    chache.get(id);
  }

}
```

I use a `WeakHashMap` with weak references, so the (distributed) garbage collection process will remove unused remote objects even if they are in the map. My remote objects register themselves by calling `RemoteObjectCache.register(this)` in theire constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The idea in RMI is to define remote method parameters and return values as the remote interface, not the remote object.

So the cast in the `delete()` method should be to `MyRemoteInterface`, not to `RemoteMyObject`.

Likewise:

```
public Collection<RemoteMyObject> getItems() throws RemoteException {
```

Change that signature to:

```
public Collection<MyRemoteInterface> getItems() throws RemoteException {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately it did not solve the problem. In fact I am able to cast the the argument to `MyRemoteInterface` but then I can't access the `MyObject` I want to remove from the Collection on the server. The `RemoteCollectionInterface` defines the method signature as a bounded wildcard type `< ? extends MyRemoteInterface> getItems()`, so this part works nicely and I can use this Method.

Comment: You need a Map so you can go from the stubs you will receive as parameters to the actual exported objects they belong to.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did at last.